# How to pickle a function in Python?

Tags: python, pickle

I  defined a simple function and pickled it
However when I deserialised it in another file
I couldn’t load it back

I got an error

Comment: The related code, please.

Comment: What was your error message?

Comment: You should write code you wrote, we can't understand how much you understand about the problem. And of course you should write the error details.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

```
import pickle 

def fnc(c=0):
    a = 1
    b = 2
    return a,b,c

f = open('example', 'ab')

pickle.dump(fnc, f)
f.close()

f = open('example', 'rb')

fnc = pickle.load(f)

print(fnc)
print(fnc())
print(fnc(1))
```

```
<function fnc at 0x7f06345d7598>
(1, 2, 0)
(1, 2, 1)
```

Comment: @Meet Lalwani if you have a specific error, let me know!

Comment: After load function from pickle file, you have to close the file object!! I think this a simple and smart way to implement this problem!!

Comment: Should I still define the function in the new file(plss excuse me if this sounds dumb I am beginner)

Answer (score -1):

You can also do it using `shelve` module. I believe it still uses pickle to store data, but very convenient feature of it is that you can store data in a form of key-value pairs. For example, if you store a ML model, you can store training data and/or feature column names along with the model itself which makes it more convenient.

```py
import shelve

def func(a, b):
    return a+b

# Now store function
with shelve.open('foo.shlv', 'w') as shlv:
    shlv['function'] = func

# Load function
with shelve.open('foo.shlv', 'r') as shlv:
    x = shlv['function']
    print(x(2, 3))
```